# Rstudio loading workspace failed

Tags: r, rstudio

When I want to work with Rstudio , I get an error

```
“bad restore file magic number” error in R
```

[image]

I tried to do research on the internet to solve the problem but it does not work

Any idea please !!!

Comment: Do you need that workspace data or not? If not, just delete that `RData` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems as if R tries to automatically load a previously saved workspace that's corrupted. Take a look at your home directory and check if you can locate the .RData file. Delete that one and the problem should go away.

On Windows that's most likely in the folder:

C:/Users/YourUserName/Documents

Remember that the file is only the extension .RData and is -depending on your settings- sometimes automatically saved by both R and RStudio.  (depending on your settings it might ask to save the workspace on exiting, do so without asking or don't do it at all. see also `?quit`)

Because it's only an extension, on Windows it will be a hidden file. In order to be able to see and delete it, change your Windows settings so you can see hidden files.

Comment: I have deleted the .Rdata, .Rhistory and .rstudio directory's from my home dir as well as deleted all of these files from my R project directories.... yet Rstudio server is still try (unsuccessfully) to load the session. On ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Garglesoap Is that with the same error message, or is RStudio simply not starting up? Because if it is the latter, you should first check whether you have the latest version, and if so, try the RStudio forums. Because then it's another problem. I had problems on an Ubuntu system with RStudio as well lately, so it might even be a bug. Also in that case RStudio will want to hear fro you.